# Change quickly icons of a folder and its subfolders

Tags: folders, icon, automation

I need to change the folder icons of a selected folder and all the subfolder inside it with the same PNG image.

Accept any mode (Bash scripts, Automator workflows and so on...), I have no preferences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a solution using the macOS GUI:

1. **Copy your PNG image** to your clipboard.
2. With Finder.app, **open the folder** whose folder and subfolder icons you want to change
3. Press CMD + F to **start a search**
4. In the *Search menu bar* **click the folder's name**. "This Mac" must not be selected.
5. enter **`kind:folder`**
6. In the results **select all** folders (CMD+A).
7. Press CMD+Shift+I to **show the Inspector**.
8. In the Inspector window **select the blue folder icon** in the upper left
9. Press CMD+V to **paste your PNG image**. All selected folder icons will update their icon.

Let me know if this works for you.

Sometimes you have to click twice on the icon in the Inspector window in order to paste the image successfully.

Comment: This very smart trick worked for me! 

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you!